# C programming- Convert from char * to char array?

Tags: c

This is my code

```
char *output;

char store[100];

output = store;
```

How do I store the contents of output to the char array?

Comment: by copying them to the array..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately arrays are not assignable in C
You could always use:

`memcpy(store, output, sizeof(store))` (string.h)

to copy the memory though.

Comment: If we deal with genuine NUL terminated string, `strcpy` or `strncpy` is better

Answer (score 1):

char pointers can't store `100 chars`. They can point to a memory address that has 100 chars, so `output = store;` is one way.

If you want to allocate memory space for them, you can use:

```
char *output;
char store[100];
output = malloc(100);
memcpy(output, store, sizeof(store));
```

However, if `store` holds strings (NUL-terminated), I would use `strncpy` instead, which will stop the copy if a `'\0'` is encountered :

```
strncpy(output, store, sizeof(store));
```